# Python Download Script

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this, the Progress % is backwards, does anyone know how to make it 0% at the beginning and 100% when it completes?

```
import time

x = 25
y = x
t = 0

downloading = True
while downloading:
  time.sleep(1)
  t += 1
  x -= 1
  f = ((x/y) * 100)
  print('Time:', str(t) + ',', 'Progress: ', '{0:.2}'.format(str(f)) + '%,', 'Remaining: ' + str(x), 'MB', end="\r")

  if(x == 0):
    print('\nComplete!')
    break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `(1-x/y)` instead of `x/y` in `f`.

```
import time

x = 25
y = x
t = 0

downloading = True
while downloading:
  time.sleep(0.01)
  t += 1
  x -= 1
  f = ((1-x/y) * 100)
  print('Time:', str(t) + ',', 'Progress: ', '{0:.3}'.format(str(f)) + '%,', 'Remaining: ' + str(x), 'MB', end="\r")

  if(x == 0):
    print('\nComplete!')
    break
```

Also note that you should use `'{0:.3}'.format(str(f))` so that `100%` can be displayed correctly.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for your answer, sorry I'm new to python and just learning :)